# Writing a PL SQL change script (sql developer/oracle)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an assignment for uni now where I need to write a database change script and then a rollback script. I should also do some simple checks whether the changes has been done or not. I have spent enormous time by writing the scripts because I am not skilled in plsql. The prodcut is here:

```
-- the check could be more extensive, e.g. checking the type of the column
declare 
  titleExists number;
begin
  select count(*) into titleExists
  from user_tab_columns
  where table_name = 'TITLE'
    and column_name = 'TITLE';

  if titleExists > 0 then
    execute immediate 'alter table title rename column title to name';
  end if;
end;
/

declare
  typeExists number;
begin
  select count(*) into typeExists
  from user_tab_columns
  where table_name = 'TITLE'
    and column_name = 'TYPE'
    and data_type = 'CHAR';

  if typeExists > 0 then
    execute immediate 'alter table title add (new_type varchar2(12) check (new_type in (''business'', ''mod_cook'', ''psychology'', ''popular_comp'', ''trad_cook'')))';

    execute immediate 'update title set new_type = trim(type)';

    execute immediate 'alter table title modify (new_type not null)';

    execute immediate 'alter table title drop column type';

    execute immediate 'alter table title rename column new_type to type';
  end if;
end;
/
```

The first part renames a column and the second part changes columns type and adds a check, basically turns a char column into an enum.

I would really like to know whehter I need to put every alteration in execute immediate block. Is there a simpler way of writing this?

Comment: For top marks do not forget to add exception handling ;)

Comment: Haha, screw exception handling. I will only add a comment there, something like "There should be exception handling." Also this assignment is not marked, it is either done or not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the script, but keeping myself limited to the question whether to use execute immediate:

There is not really a simpler way of writing this. The PL/SQL is modifying the database it runs on, so adding for instance the `update title` occur as a hard-coded section in the PL/SQL is not possible (it would not compile).

Also, sometimes it is possible to merge multiple statements executed through execute immediate in one big PL/SQL being send over. But PL/SQL itself does not support the DDL statements, so you need some way of dynamic SQL.

Note also that each DDL does an implicit commit, so your update is always executed and committed by the following `alter table` statement.

I think you have done great being this your first PL/SQL assignment.

Comment: I know there must be tons of issues. However, it is a school assignment. Im not willing to spend two years on it. Is there any sample of how to write a proper change script in oracle database? This must be done somehow in companies. Finally, thanks for the last sentence. It cheered me up after the hours of googling and minutes of coding :)

Comment: @Santhos Yes, we've a proper change script based upon configuration management issues since 1999... but it is really complex PL/SQL and over 600 KB of packages (plus I can't share it with you). Most companies running Oracle don't automate the database change models. Some do, depending on the skills of their DBA. And many software companies. Can you be more specific of what you are missing? Maybe I can help.

Comment: I understand that you cannot share it. I am actually not missing anything specific. I was simply courious. Thanks for your help.